# How to run AJAX request with no conflict?

Tags: wordpress

I have a function in functions.php file that makes json request. This is how I am calling this function:

```
define('IS_AJAX_REQUEST', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if (IS_AJAX_REQUEST){
loadmore();
}
```

Above code works just fine, but the problem is it conflicts with other AJAX request, for example, I see error message saying cannot execute loadmore() when I try to upload an image.

I tried following but none worked.

```
if (IS_AJAX_REQUEST && is_page()){
loadmore();
}
```

+

```
if (is_page()){
if (IS_AJAX_REQUEST){
loadmore();
   }
}
```

+

```
if (IS_AJAX_REQUEST){
if (is_page()) loadmore();  }
}
```

And here is the loadmore function

```
function loadmore(){

  header('Content-type: application/json');

 echo json_encode (array ('rsp'=>'ok',

        'payload'=> DrawPostList($_GET['tribe'], $_GET['offset']),

        'lionly'=> true,

        'tribe'=> $_GET['tribe'],

        'offset'=> $_GET['offset']+20));

 exit;
}
```

I only wanna execute loadmore() function when viewing a page. How can I do that ?

Comment: post your loadmore(); function and exact error which you are getting

Comment: @wordpresser here is loadmore function. It works fine without additional conditions. Also, This function only be called when user clicks on a button. I got that covered via Js.

Comment: i cant seem to find what actual error is, but are you following proper steps to make ajax work in wordpress ?

Comment: look here http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: @wordpresser Thanks. I did looked at it and followed but no luck. As I said, function should only triggers when user clicks on a button. Is there any way I can only allow this AJAX call to be live when user viewing a PAGE only ? So it should not conflict with other sections of WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {

    is_page() { // load script only on pages 
?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        function loadmore() {

            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: ajaxurl,
                    data: { action : 'loadmore_trigger', var1 : 'test', var2 : 'one more' }
            })
        }.done(function( response ) {
            alert(response);

        }
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}


add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore_trigger', 'loadmore_trigger');
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore_trigger', 'loadmore_trigger');

function loadmore_trigger(){

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
exit;

}
?>

<input type="submit" onclick="loadmore(); return false;"> // make ajax call on click of submit button
```